# Is the following proof of the inequality $|1-z^a|\leq\frac{\sqrt{\log^2 r+4\pi^2}}{|\log r|}(1-r^a)$ with $|z|<1,a>0$ correct?

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

Let $z=re^{i\phi}$ be a complex number from the unit disc, i.e., $r<1,\phi\in[0,2\pi)$. Then we can write $r=e^{\sigma}$ with $\sigma=\log r$. Thus, $z=re^{i\phi}=e^{\sigma}e^{i\phi}=e^{\sigma+i\phi}=e^s$, where $s=\sigma+i\phi=\log r+i\phi$.

Hence, for any $a>0$ we have the following:

$|1-z^a|=|1-e^{as}|=|\int_0^ase^{us}du|\leq|s||\int_0^ae^{u\sigma}du|=|\frac{s}{\sigma}|(1-e^{a\sigma})=|\frac{s}{\sigma}|(1-r^a)=\Biggl|\frac{\log r+i\phi}{\log r}\Biggr|(1-r^a)=\frac{\sqrt{\log^2 r+\phi^2}}{|\log r|}(1-r^a)\leq\frac{\sqrt{\log^2 r+4\pi^2}}{|\log r|}(1-r^a)$

Comment: Looks ok. As a sidenote: the inequality is not very strong. For all $a > \frac{1}{\pi}$ the simpler inequality $|1 -  z^a |  \leq 1 + r^a$ is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems fine. Note, that you may do slightly better if you look at $-\pi < \phi\leq \pi$.